# if statement with unsigned long Integer - c++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

In the following snip of code, the `myGlobalInt` variable is an `unsigned long int`.  I'm running this code in Embarcadero C++Builder.

The first `ShowMessage()` popup correctly shows the value for `myGlobalInt` and it is larger than `86399`.  But, the `ShowMessage()` inside the `if` statement never fires.

```
ShowMessage(myGlobalInt);
if (myGlobalInt > 86399) {
    ShowMessage("Job timer stops at 24 hours.");
}
```

**Edit**: Below shows all of the relevant code so you can repeat and hopefully verify my results.  This is built in Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo in a simple Multi-Device C++ Application.

In the `Project.cpp` file, I have the following relavent code, just after the includes:

```
//---- Global variables ---
unsigned long int myGlobalInt;       // used to track seconds
int jobInt;            // used to track which job is accruing time
```

In the `Unit.cpp` file for my one Form, I have the following code just after the includes:

```
extern unsigned long int  myGlobalInt;  // seconds counter
extern int jobInt;  // which job is accruing time
```

When enabled, the Timer I'm using on the Form fires every 1 second.  It has the following relavent code:

```
myGlobalInt++;   // eventually this exceeds 86,399.

ShowMessage(myGlobalInt);
if (myGlobalInt > 86399UL) {
    ShowMessage("Job timer stops at 24 hours.");
}
```

Without the `UL` suffix on the `86399` literal, the `"Job timer stops at 24 hours."` message never happens.

**Edit**:  Following advice, I've created a simple console code as below.  But, this code works fine - and without the `UL` suffix!

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int goofy;
    unsigned long int myGlobalInt = 90000;
    if (myGlobalInt > 86399) {
        std::cout << "Big number";
    }
    std::cin >> goofy;     //this is just to hold the console open
    return 0;
}
```

My original problem (that was fixed by putting `UL` on end of the `86399` literal) must have something to do with the fact that I declared the `unsigned long int` as a global variable (in the `Project.cpp` file) and then brought it into my `Unit.cpp` for use with the `extern` code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: OK, done.  I hope it is repeatable.

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't. https://wandbox.org/permlink/9RUlGfEd1Ldfu1uF Works even with values that don't fit into `int`, as it should. https://wandbox.org/permlink/CQqKfSant3dDcEv1

Comment: You can verify here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7aa94d3ff41d9c1 not repeatable

Comment: @relayman357 No, that is not a [MCVE]. It is not complete, I can't put this in a source file and compile it. If I modify it to make it compilable, it doesn't produce the behavior you describe.

Comment: Did you try to repeat it in Rad Studio 10.2?

Comment: Sorry guys, other than giving you the code (I'd be happy to via a link but i don't think that is allowed here?) i don't know that else to do.

Comment: @relayman357 *"Did you try to repeat it in Rad Studio 10.2?"* Unless this compiler implements some dialect of C++ (in that case, please retag accordingly) or is *terribly* broken (in that case, don't use it), choice of compiler is irrelevant. C++ is standardized to guarantee portability across compilers.

Comment: @relayman357 *"i don't know that else to do."* Read the links we gave you, narrow down the problem and then present that MCVE.

Comment: I'm following you - and I agree with what your saying - but i'm not making it up.  This is happening exactly as i describe.  The Rad Studio 10.2 help says that the compiler is a Clang-enhanced C++ Compiler BCC64, clang version 3.3 and LLVM version 3.3.   I guess it is just not promoting the literal to unsigned long on its own.

Comment: Something like this is certainly not broken in clang3.3. If that "Clang-enhanced C++ Compiler BCC64" is supposed to implement C++ and those examples from my wandbox links actually break, you should file a bugreport there I suppose. That would be a *serious* blunder on their part though.

Comment: `myGlobalInt` being global or extern makes no significant difference, the same promotion rules apply. You'll have to keep digging I'm afraid.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, i think the issue is that the compiler cannot tell from the context that the 86399 literal should be considered an unsigned long integer.  After reading the section on "integer" on page 8 of the following i decided to try adding "UL" to the end of 86399: http://helpcentreonline.com/article/primitiv_console_bcc.pdf

This worked and the code runs properly now.  Here is the final version:

```
ShowMessage(myGlobalInt);
if (myGlobalInt > 86399UL) {
   ShowMessage("Job timer stops at 24 hours.");
}
```

Hope this helps the next newbie.  ;-)

Comment: If `myGlobalInt` is `unsigned long` , then `86399` would be promoted to `unsigned long` anyways due to the usual arithmetic conversions, so this cannot be the solution to the actual problem.

Comment: Adding the UL was the only thing i changed in my code.  I can make a video showing it but i'm not sure how i can prove it otherwise.  Suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest you actually present that MCVE. Your "fix" probably worked by chance, there is most certainly some UB like array-out-of-bounds-access, use-after-free or a race in the picture.

Comment: @relayman357 -- the way to show it is to chop out code. You don't need that Windows stuff; just write the values to `std::cout` in a console application. If you're right about what the problem is, that will show it.

Comment: I've never heard of Embarcadero c++ builder. Perhaps this is a standard compliance issue unique to that particular implementation? It may use a 2 byte `int` and incorrectly implement arithmetic conversions.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The former would not matter, and if the latter is the case, that would be quite a big screw up. I hope no such compiler would be used for anything production related.